# Oracle SQL changes in sqldeveloper are not reflected in EFCore

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, oracle-sqldeveloper, ef-core-2.2, data-persistence

I have not used oracle with EF before, so I dont know how to deal with this weird thing happening. And cant find solutions online.

When I make changes on SQLdeveloper (updates/inserts) using sql, they are shown in SQLdeveloper, but not in app using EF.

When I make changes in EF, those are shown in SQLdeveloper.

In other words the APP shows data only from EF, but on SQLdeveloper I can see both.
I have restarted the app multiple times and they are still not showing.

**EDIT:**

By make changes I mean any data changes. Like :

```
insert into table
(columns)
values(values);
```

And SQLdeveloper says `inserted 1 row`. 
And when I `select * from table` I see the row.

In the app, when I do inspect of `context.TableSET.ToList()` the row is not there.

but if I do

```
context.TableSET.Add(tableobj); 
context.SaveChanges();
```

I can see the row using SQLdeveloper

Comment: Can you please share the whole code --> **I make changes on SQLdeveloper (updates/inserts) using sql**

Comment: and you are sure that after doing any change in SQL Developer, you execute the `commit` statement and then you are checking in EF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute the `COMMIT` statement after executing your changes so that it gets reflected in another session.

EF is using another session and Without `COMMIT`, changes are only reflected in the current session, That is why it is visible in SQL Developer and not in EF.

Cheers!!